# How can I select esNext in the menu of typescript in visual studio 2017

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have the following error when I used dynamic import with typescript in my visual studio 2017: TS1323(TS) L'importation dynamique est prise en charge uniquement quand l'indicateur '--module' a la valeur 'commonjs' ou 'esNext'.

So, I try to change my setting of my project, but there is not esNext in the list of module. I try to modify the project manually but the error still stay there. And I don't want use a .config file for typescript.

[image: a config]

Any solution on how I can suppress this error or add the option of esNext in vs2017?

Answer (score 0):

I think your typescript project will have 1 file name `tsconfig.json` so you can change the module type to esNext like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esNext",
        // other prop
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a tsconfig.json file. The compiler options are directly in the .csproj (<TypeScriptModuleKind>).